# Finding location and moving directions on a grid in Java

Tags: java, grid, location, distance

I have a tester class I'm all set on, I'm just unsure on how to make this work with my blueprint. Here's what I'm trying to do:

"You exist on an infinite grid of avenues and streets where positions are represented as a coupling of integers (avenue,street). You can use negatives. Now consider a drunkard that randomly picks one of four directions at an intersection and then stumbles to the next intersection doing the same and so on. Write a class Drunkard to simulate this way of being given the drunkard's starting point. Your Drunkard class should have as instance variables the drunkard's current avenue (x location) and current street (y location). Your class should have a method called `step( )` that moves the drunkard to the next randomly chosen adjacent intersection. Your class should have another method called `fastForward(int steps)` that takes an integer as input (call it steps) and moves the drunkard steps intersections from his current location. Your class should have a method `getLocation( )` that returns a String indicating the drunkard's current location. Finally your class should have a method called `howFar( )` that reports the drunkards distance in blocks from where he started calculated using the Manhattan distance metric."

What do you recommend? Any help will do, thanks.

Here is what I have for my blueprint so far.

```
java.util.Random;

class Drunkard 
{
    private int avenue;
    private int street;

    Drunkard(int avenue, int street) {
        this.avenue = avenue;
        this.street = street;
    }

    Random rand = new Random();

    void moveUp(){
        this.street -= 1;
    }
    void moveDown(){
        this.street += 1;
    }
    void moveRight(){
        this.avenue += 1;
    }
    void moveLeft(){
        this.avenue -= 1;
    }
    void getLocation(){
        int avenue = parseInt("avenue");
        int street = parseInt("street");
        System.out.println("Location: " + avenue + ", " + street);
    }
    void fastForward(int steps)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < steps.length; i++}{
        }
    }
    void step(){
    }
    void howFar(){
        int distance = Math.abs(x1-x0) + Math.abs(y1-y0);
    }
}
```

And I need to it correspond with this tester class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DrunkardTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the starting avenue integer: ");
    int avenue = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the starting street integer: ");
    int street = input.nextInt();

    // instantiate
    Drunkard jeff = new Drunkard(avenue,street);

     //move 100 intersections
    jeff.fastForward(100);

    //find current location
    String location = jeff.getLocation();

    // get distance from start
    int distance = jeff.howFar();

    System.out.println("Current location: " + location);
    System.out.println("This is " + distance + " blocks from your origin.");

    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you could explain what you need in more detail  or precisely?

Comment: Do you need help on implementation of Step, fast forward and howFar() methods?

Comment: @sathiyaseelan I need my first class to correspond with everything in the Tester class below it. My first class has errors. My user is supposed to replicate a drunk, so they will only move in random directions. I need to move either up, down, left or right. They need to be recorded. The record is for every intersection I'm at. So every choice will result in a new street + avenue combination. There must be an option for me to move a specific amount of intersections if requested besides the default one. The amount of moves need to be calculated and recorded for every instance. Thank you!

Comment: @sathiyaseelan Yes, I need help on all of those or anything else you feel is not correct or properly addressing what is in the prompt or Tester class.

Comment: @Lorber Don't remove the content of your question after you get an answer, that's not how this site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to keep track of starting intersection of drunkard,

You have to keep the instance variables as something like following

```
private int startAvenue;
private int startStreet;
```

And modify the constructor to store the startAvenue and StartStreet values.

```
Drunkard(int avenue, int street) {
    this.startAvenue = avenue;
    this.startStreet = street;
}
```

Now the drunkard instance has its start location always.

Now we can focus on step method,

```
void step(){
    int nextMove = rand.nextInt(3);
    if(nextMove == 0)
      moveUp();
    else if(nextMove == 1)
      moveDown();
    else if(nextMove == 2)
      moveLeft();
    else
      moveRight();
}
```

In fastForward(), simply invoke step() method inside the for loop

```
 void fastForward(int steps)
{
    for (int i=0; i < steps.length; i++}{
      step();
    }
}
```

In howFar() method,

```
int howFar(){
    int distance = Math.abs(startAvenue-avenue) + Math.abs(startStreet-street);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is amazing! One thing, though. I can't subtract avenue or street from startAvenue or startStreet in howFar() because they don't exist now. What do you recommend I do to create a method for current street & avenue position + counter?

Comment: what do you mean by they don't exist? I assume you keep them as instance variable as well.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake! I put them back in. Thank you so much! But I am still getting this last error.

Drunkard.java:36: int cannot be dereferenced
        for (int i=0; i < steps.length; i++){

Comment: steps is a primitive type. So it cannot have methods. replace the condition in for loop with i<steps . Thanks